# Detect item changed - QtTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Is it possible to detect a situation when user changes cell value in `QtTableWidget` manually? I used `table.itemChanged.connect(func)` but I think that `itemChanged` detects all changes so I'm unable to refill the table in function `func`.

When user change `QtTableWidget` item value, the program runs method (func) which refills whole table. The problem is that `table.itemchanged` detects all changes so it returns error: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` because func generates many `itemChanged` signals.

Comment: You can create your own delegate (`QItemDelegate`) and handle used input there.

Answer (score 2):

You can block signals in your func.

```
func(...)
{
...
table.blockSignals(true);
// do your change here
table.blockSignals(false);
...
}
```

Or use the newer [QSignalBlocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html).